# deny apache2 access after failed login attempts

Tags: php, apache2

after 4 failed username/password login attempts, I would like to deny the IP access to the server. I've denied access to the web server before by adding the IP or block to the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file like so.

```
<Location "/">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from 1.2.3.4/30 3.4.5.6/15
    Deny from 9.4.3.4
</Location>
```

anyone know how to do this programmatically with PHP, or perhaps have Apache2 query mysql for an 'IP-deny list' at a set interval?

thanks!

**edit for clarification**

on completed form submit, mysql is queried for username. If username found, the script continues with checking pw, then later to check for failed logins. If the failed login counter >=4 the user's acct is locked, but they can still access the server.

If username NOT found, i query a dif. table for user's IP. If IP found AND login_counter >=4 block IP from server using method like above apache2 httpd.conf.

****final edit/thoughts**

I'm afraid I would open a bigger security vulnerability if I were to give www-data user perms. to edit .htaccess file, and since there's not a way to ref. a file inside of .htaccess that would be www-data writable, here's my solution.

If username not in db, write IP to db and keep track of failed attempts per IP. Upon site re-visit, if the IP is in db and attempts >=4, login script die(). Next, I'll Write an external script (not accessible by www-data) that polls the db each night for IP's where attempts >=4 and add them to .htaccess.

Comment: I tend to do this on the login page itself using a login_log table with each row being a fail or success, if 10 failed attempts are done in 5 mins I show them a nasty captcha that they must fill in as well to prove they are not botting my form. Though you gotta be clearer, is this supposed to block users logging into your site or into your server?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Turns out you can include files inside `.htaccess`, so I made some changes.

So what happens here is that you take the `.htaccess` file, remove the last line `Allow from all` then append the new deny rule and then add the removed line.

Your `.htaccess` file would be like this:

```
order Deny,Allow
Deny from 9.4.3.4
Allow from all
```

When a user exceeds login attempts you do this:

```
$file = file('.htaccess');
array_pop($file);
$fh = fopen('.htaccess','w');
fwrite($fh, implode('',$file));
fclose($fh);
$fh = fopen('.htaccess', 'a');
fwrite($fh, 'Deny from '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
fwrite($fh, 'Allow from all']);
fclose($fh);
```

Well, this is the basic idea, you can take it and customize it and apply it to your own environment

Comment: i didn't mean anything negative about my comment, and I really appreciate your help. Im somewhat new to apache2 and was just wondering if an .htaccess file is the same thing as a httpd.conf file.

Comment: alright, then I misunderstood you (long day at work). Well, `.htaccess` is not `httpd.conf` but there many configurations you can override or even add using the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: kk. I'm reading about .htaccess now; I might have some questions in a few. thanks again!

Comment: Just as a little thing. IP block isn't very reliable way to block a computer especially if that IP ain't static. You'll find that computer will just come back with a new IP, infact some server automate renewing of IPs once every 10 mins...so I have to be honest when I say that your just wasting your time.

Comment: @Sammaye, I totally agree with you. Make your code a bit smart, when you see brute force attack then lock the account for a minute or two -> you'll greatly reduce the efficiency of the attack and the same time it won't be much of inconvenience for the real user.

Comment: thanks for suggestions. could anyone comment on how to reference 'blacklist.conf' from .htaccess, so that I don't have to allow .htaccess writable by www-data user?

Comment: @dan, unfortunately that's not possible.